# I need to implement a fuzzy string search with Spring + ArangoDB

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, arangodb, aql

My technology stack: Spring Boot + ArangoDB.
I have entities:

```
Person {
NameDetails nameDetails;
}

NameDetails {
List<Name> name;
}

Name {
NameValue nameValue;
}

NameValue {
String singleStringName;
}
```

There is a REST endpoint that accepts the String fullName parameter. I need to write an AQL query to the ArangoDB database to search for the fullName parameter.

Example:
Person.nameDetails.name[*].nameValue.singleStringName has the string "Randa Setiawan Nugraha" and the endpoint receives the parameter "Randa Nugraha", then the entity record with the string "Randa Setiawan Nugraha" should return. So there can be different variations of the incoming parameter to find the record.

How can I do this?

Comment: You haven't asked a question.